# QField edition: deplace point object

Tags: point, editing, qfield

I would like tu use QField to update localisation of points objects that their fields are already informed.
With the editing tool I don't manage to deplace point despite I see several "how to".
There is someone to describe how it can be done?

Answer (score 0):

In QField, when you are in 'browse mode' and in the right layer (!), select the point/feature you want to move. In the upcoming edit mode, select the feature again and look for the sign tot move a point/node (red circle on the printscreen). Qfield will now take you back to the map en you can move the point/node which changed color.

Good luck.
[image]

Comment: Great, It works.

Answer (score 0):

in newer QField versions (e.g. 2.3.4) it is now easier to deplace point objects.

1. When You are in browse mode, select feature on the corresponding layer. Tap on the object, so that You can see the attributes.
2. In the menue, tap on the 3 points-icon on the right of the popup-window.
3. Select 'Move selected objects'. Move the screen (the selected object will stay on his place) until the object is on the new place.
4. Confirm the new location with the green accept button on the right bottom of the screen.

[image: Mode selected object]
[image: Move screen and confirm new location]